# Error interception

Tags: expl3

The code in the MWE allows `\myMacro` to process either a `tokenlist`, `integer`, or `floating point item` by setting the appropriate optional `#2 parameter`. My question at the outset was going to be:

(1) Does `expl3` provide a way to intercept an error, step over the offending statement, take remedial action and continue the compilation, something similar to `Try...Catch...Finally` in `VB.Net` for example? If it did, one could write some very tidy macro templates that accept type-independent input parameters ... just dreaming!

(2) The more urgent question now is: why do calls `5: \myMacro{13a5}[int]` and `6: \myMacro{3.14159}[int]` below produce the results they do rather than compilation errors?

As an aside, I am not sure what goes on with the indentation in the MWE either.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%   VARIABLE DECLARATIONS:
\tl_new:N \l_aux_rn_tl
\int_new:N \l_aux_rn_int
\fp_new:N \l_aux_rn_fp
\NewDocumentCommand\myMacro{m O{tok}}
    {
        \str_case:nnTF {#2} 
                    {
                        {tok}
                        {token:~
                        \tl_set:Nn \l_aux_rn_tl {#1}
                        \l_aux_rn_tl
                        }                   
                        {int}
                        {integer:~
                        \int_set:Nn \l_aux_rn_int {#1}
                        \int_use:N \l_aux_rn_int
                        }                       
                        {fp}
                        {float:~
                        \fp_set:Nn \l_aux_rn_fp {#1}
                        \fp_use:N \l_aux_rn_fp
                        }
                    }
                    {}
                    {invalid~2nd~param}                     
    }   %   end \myMacro

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
1: \verb+\myMacro{342561}+ \\
\myMacro{342561}\\
2: \verb+\myMacro{342561}[tok]+ \\
\myMacro{342561}[tok]\\
3: \verb+\myMacro{342561}[int]+ \\
\myMacro{342561}[int]\\
4: \verb+\myMacro{3.14159}[fp]+ \\
\myMacro{3.14159}[fp]\\
5: \verb+\myMacro{13a5}[int]+ \\
\myMacro{13a5}[int]\\
6: \verb+\myMacro{3.14159}[int]+ \\
\myMacro{3.14159}[int]\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: The question about “error checking” is a bit too generic. The problem with `\int_set:Nn \l_aux_rn_int {13a5}` has to do with how TeX recognizes a `<number>`. Input such as `\count255=13a5` is perfectly legal: it stores 13 in the count register and typesets `a5`.

Comment: As @egreg notes, we don't error-check all input, we leave that to TeX (performance otherwise would be a real issue). I'm not sure why you can't store your input as a `tl` in all cases here, although it also seems a pretty poorly defined input form.

Comment: @josephwright @egreg Admittedly my expectations in regard to intercepting and checking errors was over the top, and have learnt to do without it: with my matrix macros I want to do computations prior to typesetting them; feeding integer and floating point elements to these macros through `seq-type` parameters works fine -  as long as the format of the argument is kosher I can assign them to `int_` and `fp_` variables without any problem.

Comment: @JosephWright ... as always, my original MWE is what is left after everything is removed that has no immediate bearing on my question. But even with that caveat it looks pretty poor.