# “new” and “set” in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3

I have some questions in LaTeX， There are many "new" and "set" in LaTeX3， I don't quite understand when “new” is needed，such as

```
\int_set:Nn \l_my_int{12}
```

An error occurred

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \l_my_int                                 
l.11 \int_set:Nn \l_my_int {12}
```

also，i use

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl{\maketitle}
```

it is normal

Hope to explain to me，thanks！

Comment: Read section 4.3.1 "defining functionses" in interface3.pdf.

Comment: Also you can't quite rely on doing wrong things will absolutely raise error. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270296/error-interception#comment649128_270296  . (actually expl3 has some debug mode or something, didn't try it)

Comment: See also [latex3 - When should one use a local or global variable in LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406092/when-should-one-use-a-local-or-global-variable-in-latex)

Answer (score 10):

In `expl3`, all variables should be declared before use, as this is the convention for the language. At the implementation level, some `expl3` variables are TeX registers, whereas others are TeX macros. The latter can be created without allocation, but registers need to be allocated before use (at least using a name).

There is checking code available that will pick up if you 'shortcut' and forget to declare a variable before assigning it, even if behind the scenes it's a macro. However, as that slows things down, it's not active by default. You can active it with

```latex
\RequirePackage[enable-debug,check-declarations]{expl3}
```